# How to Update DataTable

Tags: vb.net, datatable, updates

I have a main `DataSet` which contains several `DataTables`. These different DataTables are bound to their DataGridView's DataSource respectively.

My problem is whenever I modify something in the display area such as the description textbox below and then click on save....

[image: Description] <<< To >>> [image: Modified Description]

The DataGridView doesn't have the replicated changes, as seen here:
[image: DataGridView Results]

I need a way to update the DataTable ... My save button successfully saves the information. I am quite new to DataSets and DataTables so this is my first time trying to update a DataTable. I doubt I need to reload the information in the DataTable, there must be something more efficient?

Comment: What is exactly the display area and what is linked to? To the dataset taken as source by the DataGridView?

Comment: @varocarbas The display area is just where the information is loaded into and modified when I click on a save button. It saves that information to the database, but the saved data is not replicated into the DataTable because I haven't reloaded it or ... modified that given row in the DataTable

Comment: Bear in mind that the usual proceeding is: setting a datasource to the DataGridView at the start; and then allowing some kind of modification of the DataGridView directly (via the display area you are mentioning for example). These modifications do not affect the source, but the involved DataGridView cells. If you want to affect the source, the changes will not be reflected in the DataGridView immediately, you have to refresh/re-link. If I understand what you want rightly, what I would do in your situation would be performing two parallel editions at the same time: DB and DGV

Comment: @varocarbas Right. I understand that, I searched on it and apparently a TableAdapter would be needed along with my DataSet? Once my modifications are made and replicated to the database, the DataTable needs to be updated as well. That will replicate the changes in the DataGridView (since it is bound to the DataTable). I'm just not sure how to do so ...

Comment: If you change the DataSource of the DataGridView the changes will NOT be updated immediately. If you want to modify specific fields, why not updating the DataGridView directly?

Comment: @varocarbas Well, it seems to me that if I update the DataGridView manually (avoiding the DataTable that's bound to the DataGridView) I am contradicting the DataTable's purpose ... I figured there was an easy way to update a DataTable's row... Which would then be replicated back to the DataGridView

Comment: Why are you contradicting the DataTable's purpose? Its purpose is allowing a quick initial population of the DataGridView. Once the data is in, you are expected to change the DataGridView itself.

Comment: @varocarbas I was able to solve it by finding the row in the DataTable. Once that was done, all I do is modify the row's attribute with the new information. Afer that, voilà! The DataGridView's information is updated. Also, thank you very much for your help. :)

Comment: No problem. But is the DataGridView updated automatically after you change the DataSource? Without doing anything else? Don't trust this behaviour too much (or you would get in troubles at some point).

Comment: @varocarbas Yeah, the DataGridView is updated without any modifications after my DataTable modifs. Hopefully I won't run in too many problems! I thought I would have needed to unlink it from the DataGridView and relink it after.

Comment: There you have quite a few complains on this matter: https://www.google.com/search?q=datagridview+not+updating+from+dataset&oq=datagridview+not+updating+from+dataset&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.14899j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#fp=ed85340f5854ca84&q=datagridview+not+updating+from+datasource Just in case I always prefer to update the DataGridView directly; but if it works like this for you, go ahead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Updating a DataTable With Unknown Indexes

For more information: [How to: Edit Rows in a DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tat996zc.aspx)

In order to edit an existing row in a DataTable, you need to locate the DataRow you want to edit, and then assign the updated values to the desired columns.

---

**Update existing records in typed datasets (Row index not known)**

Assign a specific DataRow to a variable using the generated FindBy method, and then use that variable to access the columns you want to edit and assign new values to them.

```
Dim Description As String = "Hello World Modified"

'Update DataTable
Dim Row As DataSet1.DataTableRow
Row = DataSet1.DataTableRow.FindByPrimaryKey(PK)
Row.Description = Description
```

---

**Update existing records in untyped datasets (Row index not known)**

Use the Select method of the DataTable to locate a specific row and assign new values to the desired columns

```
Dim Description As String = "Hello World Modified"

'Update DataTable
Dim Row() As Data.DataRow
Row = DataSet1.Tables("Table1").Select("PrimaryKey = '10'")
Row(0)("Description") = Description
```

---

Once this is done, I don't need to refresh anything else - my DataGridView has the latest information.